# MATLAB Engine API runs forever if code is separated

Tags: matlab, api

I'm trying to access MATLAB through Engine with MetaTrader Terminal 4
( a trading software from MetaQuotes [metatrader4](/questions/tagged/metatrader4) )

I use a DLL file to communicate between MetaTrader and MATLAB.

In the code, if I put this code in a single function, it works.

But if I separate it into two distinct functions, it runs forever/bugs out

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <memory.h>

#include "engine.h"

using namespace std;

#define MT4_EXPFUNC __declspec(dllexport)

Engine  *pEng      = NULL;
mxArray *closev    = NULL;
double  *closevp   = NULL;
mxArray *getPArray = NULL;

MT4_EXPFUNC void InitEngine( int dummy )
{
    pEng = engOpen( NULL );
}

MT4_EXPFUNC void InitCloseBuffer( int size )
{
    closev = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( 1, size, mxREAL );
    if ( closev != NULL )
         closevp = mxGetPr( closev );

 // ------------------------------------------------------------------
 // the following code bugs when separated from the code above
 // and put in another function called right after this one

    engPutVariable( pEng, "closev",  closev );
    engEvalString(  pEng, "[mainNet] = PTrainInit();" );
    engEvalString(  pEng, "[hitrate, mainNet] = PTrain(mainNet, closev);" );

    engEvalString(  pEng, "outGetP = PGetPrediction(mainNet, closev)" );

    getPArray = engGetVariable( pEng, "outGetP" );

    double *p;
    if ( getPArray != NULL )
        p = mxGetPr( getPArray );

// end of the separated code
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

I need to separate both functions though,
because I need to fill **`closev`** with values.

**What am I doing wrong?**

thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found the answer: initially I had made a standalone MATLAB Project, that was working fine but **`closev`** was column-wise and in the DLL **`closev`** is row-wise.

Also, populating `closev` and then using the second, separated, function was a totally different use of the function insides than with `closev` not populated.

These two things made it look strange error-wise though.

Glad I could make it work.

JfLB